# PHP PDO multi-Instance class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My apologies if I got this post wrong, my first one.

I have a multi user application with mysql back-end. All user related routines including session tracking is relying on mysql tables.
The problem I'm seeing is db connection occasionally disappears. For example when checking user session when navigating the site nothing is returned from DB so users get logged out (application is designed to do that). All php classes use the same Database class which provides PDO routines i.e `db = new Database();`. From what I gather I need clone and instance checking included in the Database class but I'm not too sure how that is implemented.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
class Database{

    private $host;     
    private $user;     
    private $pass;     
    private $dbname;   
    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){

        require('config file');

        $this->host = host
        $this->user = user
        $this->pass = password
        $this->dbname = dbname
        // Set DSN
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';port=3306'.';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // Set options
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => TRUE,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => TRUE,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
            try{
                    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
                }
        // Catch any errors
            catch(PDOException $e){
            error_log(__CLASS__.'::'.$e);
                    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
                }
            }

    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        }


    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                     break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }           
            }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
        }


    public function execute(){
        try{
            return $this->stmt->execute();
            }
        catch(PDOException $e){
                        error_log(__CLASS__.'::'.$e);
            }
        }

    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

    public function rowCount(){
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
        }

    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        }

    public function beginTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
        }

    public function endTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->commit();
        }

    public function cancelTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->rollBack();
        }

    public function debugDumpParams(){
        return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
        }

    public function close(){
        $this->dbh  = null;
        return 1;
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: First of all, you need to read this article, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes). 2. Wile regarding your assumptions - they are wrong. If your connection disappears, you have to investigate, in which circumstances it happens.

Comment: To elaborate on the problem: this happens when multiple browsers are navigating parts of the site. For debugging purposed I've added these few lines to db class: ` public function single(){
                $this->execute();
                $row = $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                error_log(__CLASS__.' row:: '.$row);
                return $row;
                } ` and what I see in the log is: Database row::  for a failed lookup - successful lookups have: Database row:: Array

Comment: I'm going to follow the article you've suggested as class routines are the prime suspect - very interesting article

Comment: With proper error logging(which drscribed in the article) you will get not only class (which is obvously useless) but full stack trace which will point at certain places un the code where error occurs